# Controllers within controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm somewhat new to MVC3, so I have a few questions...

I am creating a blog type website that I plan to expand to include many other things.  Currently I have an AdminController in my project that has ViewResult's for the various things I want to take control of.. so for example:

```
public ViewResult Blog()
{
    var model = db.Posts.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

and another for pages, navigation, user management etc.

My question is... I want to have an additional controller for each section... so BlogController, NavigationController, etc.  These should add to the URL as follows...

```
/Admin/Blog/Create
/Admin/Blog/Edit
/Admin/Navigation/Create
```

... and so on

I am guessing that I have to inherit from the AdminController something like:

```
public class BlogController : AdminController
```

and also create a custom route map?

Any advice or direction would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look into *areas*; basically this allows you to have another level of depth for your controllers.  In other words, you would add an "Admin" area, and then within that area, you'd have "Blog" and "Navigation" controllers.  Here's a tutorial on how to set up areas:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b19d5a/areas-in-Asp-Net-mvc3/

Comment: This works great, thank you!  I do have another question for you though.  I have the default _LogOnPartial view which is created if you use their default MVC3 website.  If I am in the Admin area, clicking "log off" gives me an error because that page doesn't exist in the Admin area.  How would I change "@Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")" to make it work?  Obviously it needs to find the correct view to return, I guess I don't know a whole lot about the ActionLink parameters.